# Assign shortcut to "Open package documentation" context menu item?

Tags: texstudio, shortcut

How to bind a keyboard shortcut to the action `Open package documentation` that appears in the context menu when right-clicking on commands in the editor?

I couldn't find it in the shortcut section of the settings, and didn't find anything after some searching online. I guess that action somehow calls `texdoc`?

Comment: Ctrl+Clicking on the package name in \usepackage{...} usually works. Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thanks! That's a nifty trick. But it does not seem to work for commands. I like the context menu action on commands because it opens the documentation at the correct position for that command.

Comment: It's not available as a default shortcut, nor is it possible to access the context menu options via a user script, unfortunately. https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907839/thread/c62c664c/